# Bootstrap mobile menu disappears after toggle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an Umbraco site that I'm integrating with Bootstrap. I've created a partial view with a navigation menu and everything seems to be working as intended with the exception of the navbar.

So when you click on the button it expands but immediately snaps back up. When you toggle it back, it almost 'pops into existence' and moves back up to close. Here is the entire output of the DOM

```
<html class="gr__localhost"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master_styles.css">
<style>@media print {#ghostery-purple-box {display:none !important}}</style></head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Pumpkin's Blog</h1>
                <p>Welcome to my blog. I'm always posting things like</p>
<ul>
<li>Photos</li>
<li>Videos</li>
<li>Arts and Crafts</li>
<li>Structural Cardboard Architecture&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p>I hope you stick around and comment.&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright 2018
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script id="wappalyzer" src="chrome-extension://gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg/js/inject.js"></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using bootstrap 3.3.7 js with bootstrap 4 css !

```html
<html class="gr__localhost"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Pumpkin's Blog - Meow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master_styles.css">
<style>@media print {#ghostery-purple-box {display:none !important}}</style></head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Pumpkin's Blog</h1>
                <p>Hi! I'm Pumpkin. Welcome to my blog. I'm always posting things like</p>
<ul>
<li>Photos</li>
<li>Videos</li>
<li>Arts and Crafts</li>
<li>Structural Cardboard Architecture&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p>I hope you stick around and comment.&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright 2018
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script id="wappalyzer" src="chrome-extension://gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg/js/inject.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. That did it.